# extjs4 - bulk insert in store cause a performance issue

Tags: grid, extjs4, store, suspend

Copying the rows from the grid and inserting into same grid in begining (insert at position 0).

It was causing performance issue, as soon as hits more than 10 rows. I started using

`store.suspendEvents(true);
 foreach(..)
 {
  r = ...
  store.insert(0, r);
 }
 store.resumeEvents();`

It improves a performance, as grid is no longer getting refresh with each insert of row in the store. however for some reason it throws exception while indexing the rows in the store. I think because store events are suspended, its going in some bad state.

fyi. its adding second row in the last again, where it throws with exception message.

Any other suggestion on how to handle this situation in any other way is welcome.

Comment: Why dont you want to put all data in once to the store ?

Comment: how can i do that? I have to apply some logic in order to pickup the rows..e.g. if we have 3 rows in grid, and press on copy, it needs to check certain flag and based on that if find it true, copy those rows insert it into 0th position one by one..

Answer (score 0):

You should create a store and then have the grid use that store. You can then manage the store as needed and the data will automatically be available to the grid. Something like:

```
var the_store = Ext.create('My.store.Foo', { 
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['id','name'],
    ...
    proxy: {
        ...
    }
});

var the_grid = Ext.create('My.view.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    ...
    store: the_store,
    ...
});
```